# How to deal with a unique (editable) column in order to bring better performance on retrieve the data? unique index or unique constraint?

Tags: sql-server, unique-constraint, unique-index

I have a table with a column that will be varchar unique with not null value and is editable by the user but keeping the uniqueness, filtering and ordering data will be based on that column.

What is the best way to deal with this column in order to bring the better retrieve performance?

UNIQUE CONSTRAINT or UNIQUE INDEX? Who provides best performance?
The editable requirement will affect this in the future? By the ways maybe is editable two or three times in all the record lifetime, in some records maybe never

**Mostly used queries on the future:**
`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE uniqueEditableColumn  like '%foobar%' ORDER BY uniqueEditableColumn  ASC

SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE uniqueEditableColumn  =  'foobar' ORDER BY uniqueEditableColumn  ASC

SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY uniqueEditableColumn  ASC

SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY uniqueEditableColumn  ASC, creationDateTime DESC`

The average amount or records saved will be more or less 8000
Goals: unique value - retrieve the data the most quickly as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like they are treated the same.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/147

Also, https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224827(v=sql.80).aspx has some info on it, but the only difference they found was regarding the use of FILLFACTOR when altering a table.